# Can class name and variable name be same in java?

Tags: java

In this simple program is this good practice or what?
Can we use the same name as that of class in variable? IF yes, is there some particular term to use it? Is it a good practice?

```
class test  {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
          int test;
          System.out.println(test);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes you can do it. It's called obscuring because if the variable is in scope it becomes impossible to refer to the class. It's terrible practice. Never do it.

Comment: And google Java naming conventions.

Comment: can someone give detailed explanation?

Comment: Detailed explanation for what?

Comment: Take a look http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: for this It's called obscuring because if the variable is in scope it becomes impossible to refer to the class.

Comment: or why should not i use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine from a language grammer - syntax perspective.  The compiler does not mix Class name with a variable name, since both will be in different scope.  Both mean different things to the compiler.  So it is perfectly fine to have a variable name as the same as the Class name.

The next aspect is the readability and maintainability.  In this aspect, it is a very bad practice to have both the same.  Because human beings mistake one for another.  The very question you had asked itself is a sign that it will be difficult to maintain and manage such a piece of code.

Moreover the program which you have provided will result in a compilation error saying test is not initialized.

Comment: can you explain me more about in simple terms of scope and compiler reading for it?

Comment: Please go through it .  This provides a good overview.  http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/

Answer (score 1):

There are well-defined naming conventions in Java. Class names should begin with capital letters and variables should begin with lower case letters. These rules are not enforced, so as you have discovered you can define a variable with the same name as a class. In any language, if two entities have the same name, the language designers have to make a decision about how to interpret that name. In this situation, the decision was taken that whenever the variable is in scope the name refers to the variable, not the class. As a result it is impossible to refer to the class by its simple name (you can still use its fully qualified name though). As a result it's called obscuring. You should not do it because people reading your code will get very confused if you don't follow the standard naming conventions. You should also not do it because the person reading your code may not know whether the name is referring to the variable or the class. There's no reason why they should know - this is a very obscure corner of Java and there's no reason to do it anyway.

For more information, Java Puzzlers by Bloch and Gafter includes a detailed discussion (p.180 - 182) of all the different types of name reuse in Java (overriding, hiding, overloading, shadowing and obscuring).